# Automatic connect and disconnect to an audio stream (wget) (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, firefox, audio, streaming, wget

it's about an audio stream. I already have a code. After that comes my question. :) This is about a connect on an audio stream. I start the whole thing via ./.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Basic while loop
pkill wget
counter=1
while [ $counter -le 50 ]
do
screen -S Radio_Bot_$counter -d -m wget -4 -q -c --retry-connrefused --tries=0 --waitretry=30 --timeout=5 --no-check-certificate -O /dev/null -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0' https://audiostream.com/mp3
done
echo All started!
```

I want that single or multiple connections interrupt after a certain time and after 3 seconds connect again automatically to the stream. I'm sure there is a solution. I am looking forward to your answers.

It connects to the stream. Disconnected but not automatically.